# using with block with custom class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble using a with block on a custom class in python3. Here is a quick example I came up with:

```
class Testing:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def print_text(self):
        print(self.text)

    def __enter__(self):
        print("in enter")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("in exit")
```

and in the main method:

```
 with Testing('abc') as t:
        t.print_text()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_text'
```

I've looked at a quite a few examples, and I can't figure out what I'm doing differently.

Comment: `__enter__` should return `self`

Comment: @downshift I think you should post it like an answer. It's a helpful comment that solves the OP question.

Comment: I recommend you looking at this [tutorial](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)

Comment: @ChihebNexus, I would be stealing the answer that is in the duplicate, moderators have slammed me for attempting that before

Comment: A fair point of view. You're right.